# getting average of some digits from a csv file as input and Write the averages in an output csv file in python 3

Tags: python, csv

I am learning python3 :), and I am trying to read a CSV file with different rows
and take the average of the scores for each person(in each row) 
and write it in a CSV file as an output in python 3.
The input file is like below:

```
David,5,2,3,1,6
Adele,3,4,1,5,2,4,2,1
...
```

The output file should seem like below:

```
David,4.75
Adele,2.75
...
```

It seems that I am reading the file correctly, as I print
the average for each name in the terminal, but in CSV 
output file it prints only the average of the last name 
of the input file, while I want to print all names and 
corresponding averages in CSV output file.
Anybody can help me with it?

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

these_grades = []
name_list = []
reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv', newline=''))
for row in reader:
    name = row[0]
    name_list.append(name)


    with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,
                            delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"',
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for grade in row[1:]:
            these_grades.append(int(grade))
            for item in name_list:
                writer.writerow([''.join(item), mean(these_grades)])
    print('%s,%f' % (name , mean(these_grades)))
```

Comment: `with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:` opens the file in `write` mode on _every_ iteration of the `for` loop. Every time you open a file in write mode, it wipes the existing contents. So, all of the results are written, you just then delete them when you come to the next iteration of the `for` loop

Comment: Hoist `with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as f:` to be above `for row in reader:` and then indent the following code appropriately to be within that `with` block

Comment: That said, even then, you're missing an aggregation step. I'll start an answer but probably will be beaten by now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You're not using a context manager (`with`) when you read the input file. There's no reason to use it when writing but not when reading - you consequently don't close the "input.csv" file
2. You're using a list to store data from rows. This doesn't easily distinguish between the person's name and the scores associated with the person. It would be better to use a dictionary in which the key is the person's name, and the values stored against that key are the individual scores
3. You repeatedly open the file *within* a `for` loop in `'w'` mode. Every time you open a file in write mode, it just wipes all the previous contents. You actually *do* write each row to the file, but you just wipe it again when you open the file on the next iteration.

You can use:

```
import csv
import statistics


# use a context manager to read the data in too, not just for writing
with open('input.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = list(reader)

# Create a dictionary to store the scores against the name
scores = {}

for row in data:
    scores[row[0]] = row[1:] # First item in the row is the key (name) and the rest is values


with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    # Now we need to iterate the dictionary and average the score on each iteration
    for name, scores in scores.items():
        ave_score = statistics.mean([int(item) for item in scores])
        writer.writerow([name, ave_score])
```

This can be further consolidated, but it's less easy to see what's happening:

```
with open('input.csv') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        values = row[1:]
        ave_score = statistics.mean(map(int, values))
        writer.writerow([name, ave_score])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It is 2 weeks ago I started python, and I found a lot how to write in CSV file using writerow, but non of them were iterative :)